# Hat inconsistencies in iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, winter-bash-2016, secret-hats

I'm seeing some weird hat behavior on the iOS app.

On some answers, I'm wearing the trophy hat.

> [image: Trophy]

On other answers, I'm not wearing any hat at all.

> [image: No Hat]

And on the web, I'm wearing the taco hat.

> [image: Taco Hat]

What's going on?

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 9.3.4 (Build 13G35)

Comment: Did you switch hats recently? #blamecaching

Comment: @Panda I haven't switched hats in the last 15 hours or so.

Comment: I was just about to post this... I keep wearing hats I don't even have apparently :)

Comment: I see tacos everywhere.  Not sure what would be going wrong but the app should only be caching worn hats for 5 minutes.  After that, it re-requests them with a cache-breaking parameter (just to be safe).  Nothing gets cached locally though, so you should be able to fix things by killing and restarting the app.

Comment: Related on Meta Stack Overflow: [Where is my hat in the app?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340128/2415822)