# Why aren't there hats in the iOS App?

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

Why aren't hats shown in the iOS App?

> [image: Image 1]

There does seem to be hats in the App as seen in the About page:

> [image: Image 2]

As seen, I'm using the iOS App version 1.6.2.1, the TestFlight version.

Comment: [Other people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288531/hat-inconsistencies-in-ios-app?rq=1) are reporting problems as well.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, I totally don't see any hats at all ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hats were added in 1.6.2.5.  You can get them by updating to 1.6.3.

I'm guessing that when 1.6.2.5 hit the App Store, it was removed from Test Flight so you weren't able to update too it.  I've pushed a new build to address this.

Comment: They could have just downloaded the App Store version, I switch between both all the time. My nav bar buttons got some breathing room though so I'm not complaining :)