# Hats 2017 in the apps

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ios-app, winter-bash-2017

Could we please add hats 2017 support for the apps? In particular for the iOS app. [Last year we had them.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288675/339911)

Comment: LOL.... good joke. Seriously though, the apps are frozen, their developers moved to work on other things. Heck, even serious bugs are not fixed anymore. There'll be no winterbash for them, ever. But here, take some points. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard because all functionality is already in app, I think setting the new dates would be enough in app. This also can be possibly managed on server side.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Humbug! There shall be no hats for iOS this year!

While generally speaking, the hat code is cheap (something I hear Scrooge is into), there are some elements that require manual intervention.

- The dates, URL, and even file paths change yearly, and are not publicly exposed in any API.  This is done to not spoil any surprises, given all the excellent sleuthing done by the community.  As such, settings are hardcoded in the app and require shipping, which we can't during our code freeze.
- Even if I was able to ship a small release, it's been several months since I've hit iTunesConnect, there's a new iOS out, and a new phone design.  There's a significant amount of housekeeping that would need to be done to get a build out the door.
- The SVG library used by the app is absolute rubbish and requires a lot of babysitting at the beginning of Hat Bash.  This is especially tricky when we don't reveal the real hats until launch.  One year I had to rework our SVG minifier to not do certain optimizations, another I had to completely rewrite the way the library it handles relative paths and ask Apple to expedite an app re-release.  Last year I straight up broke iOS 8 and didn't realize until the bash was almost over; dozens of users were affected!

I'm always optimistic about the future, but it was just impractical to have hats *this year*.